# Correct way to move a Linux partition to SSD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, ssd

I have a HDD with dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 16.04 in BIOS mode. The following is the representation of the partition layout:

```
|  boot  |  Primary  |                 Extended Partition                          |  Recovery  |
|        |  Windows 7|   Data1 (ext4)    |     Data2 (NTFS)    |  Ubuntu  |  Swap  |            |
```

I want to move just the Ubuntu partition to a SSD and use the space in HDD for more storage. I have a GPT partition table in the SSD which is new. Both the HDD and SSD can coexist because of Thinkpad ultrabay.

I read a lot of guides and then copied the Ubuntu partition to the SSD by with the help of Clonezilla live cd, updated the new fstab (on SSD) and ran update-grub (both when I was booted into the old Ubuntu from HDD) and I could boot into the new partition (on SSD) from the grub menu. But when I deleted the old Ubuntu partition in the HDD, grub gave me an error stating "No such disk". I thought maybe if I can manually boot into Ubuntu (on SSD) from rescue terminal, maybe I can run update-grub again and hopefully fix the issue. But from grub rescue, if I ls my SSD disk, it says "unknown filesystem".

Fortunately I had made a backup of the Ubuntu partition and restored it with clonezilla. After a bit of struggle and a weekend, I am back to my original state without the SSD.

My question is what exactly did I do wrong and what is actually the correct way to properly move the Ubuntu partition to a different disk without performing a fresh install?

Comment: Are you planning to 1. Keep the Ubuntu partition in the HDD (as a backup)? 2. Keep the bootloader in the HDD (or move it to the SSD)? -- If you keep the Ubuntu partition in the HDD, you must change some data (including the UUID) in the SSD (or in the HDD) after cloning, otherwise there will be confusion. The bootloader must point to the Ubuntu partition, that you intend to use. -- Sometimes it is easiest to make a **fresh installation** in the SSD (and that way also get the newest LTS version, 18.04.1 LTS). You might keep the home directory (copy it into a **home** partition).

Comment: You cannot clone a MBR partition to gpt. Often easier just to do a new install and then copy /home and other config files from old install. Also with gpt you need either an ESP - efi system partition or bios_grub partition for BIOS boot. I still  booted in BIOS with gpt on old system but started adding both as I thought I might move drive to a newer system later. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu I typically have ESP first and then a tiny 1 or 2MB unformatted partition with bios_grub flag.

Answer (score 1):

I would repeat all your steps but just before deleting the old Ubuntu partition, from the new Ubuntu in the SSD, execute

`sudo grub-install /dev/sdX`

Where sdX is the name of the drive you want to install it to.

After you delete the old Ubuntu, `update-grub` one more time to delete it from the list.